# Accordion layout in Extjs 4

Tags: extjs4

I have  a panel with two gridpanels as items, that is set with the accordion layout.
Based on some condition i need to show or hide the second grid panel.

```
var chartStoreGridPanel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
               id: 'chartStoreGridPanel',
               height: 200,
               layout: 'accordion',
               items: [chartStoreGridPanel1, chartStoreGridPanel2]
            });
```

I want to show or hide the "chartGridPanel2" based on some condition.

Comment: Two grids in accordion? Are you sure you don't want to use 'border'?

Comment: @sha yes... I dont want to use border..

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    items: [
        chartStoreGridPanel1,
        <condition> ? chartStoreGridPanel2 : {}
    ]
```